# Optimizing T-SQL query but getting the difference in records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

An original stored procedure T-SQL given below is running very slow and takes around 4.5 minutes to run to bring back a database of 2000+ records.

**Here it is given below(ORIGINAL QUERY)**:

```
DECLARE @Today as Smalldatetime = GetDate()
DECLARE @Organization as nvarchar(200) =  replace(db_name(), '_MSCRM', '')

--drop table #DaysToAdd
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DaysToAdd', 'U') IS NULL   
BEGIN

       CREATE TABLE #DaysToAdd (
              ipmvpopt INT,
              postretrofitslamanalysisrequired BIT,
              postretrofitpowermeteringrequired BIT,
              daysAdded INT,       
              daysAddedFinal INT
       ) 

       INSERT INTO #DaysToAdd Values
              (777790000, 0, 0, -14, 196),
              (777790000, 0, 1, -14, 196),
              (777790000, 1, 0, -14, 196),
              (777790000, 1, 1, -14, 196),
              (777790004, 0, 0, -56, 412), 
              (777790004, 0, 1, -56, 412), 
              (777790004, 1, 0, -79, 412), 
              (777790004, 1, 1, -56, 412), 
              (777790006, 0, 0, -56, 412),
              (777790006, 0, 1, -56, 412),
              (777790006, 1, 0, -79, 412),
              (777790006, 1, 1, -56, 412),
              (777790005, 0, 0, -56, 451),
              (777790005, 0, 1, -56, 451),
              (777790005, 1, 0, -56, 451),
              (777790005, 1, 1, -56, 451),
              (777790003, 0, 0, -56, 451),
              (777790003, 0, 1, -56, 451),
              (777790003, 1, 0, -56, 451),
              (777790003, 1, 1, -56, 451)
END


SELECT
       distinct
       I.filenumber as [File #],
       I.initiativename as [Initiative Name],
       I.projectname as [Project Name],
       I.mvplancompletedon as [M&V Plan Completion Date],
       I.owneridname as [Key Account Manager],
       I.approveddatestep4 as [Signed Agreement Recieved Date],
       ID.initiativedetailid,
       ID.mvcomment as [Comments],
       [Data Incomplete] =
       CASE
              WHEN (ID.mvengineerid IS NULL OR ID.ipmvpopt IS NULL OR ID.requiredmeteringequipment IS NULL OR
              ID.preretrofitpowermeteringrequired IS NULL OR ID.postretrofitpowermeteringrequired IS NULL OR
              ID.customerpostretrofitdatarequired IS NULL OR ID.preretrofitslamanalysisrequired IS NULL OR
              ID.postretrofitslamanalysisrequired IS NULL OR ID.customerbaselinedatarequired IS NULL OR
              ID.baselinecorrelationrequired IS NULL OR ID.casanalysisrequired IS NULL) THEN 'Yes'
              ELSE 'No'
       END,
       (SELECT TOP (1) [Location] = CASE WHEN (NOT S.serviceaddress_city IS NULL) THEN S.serviceaddress_city + ' / ' + S.name ELSE S.name END FROM Filtered_site S WHERE S.siteid = ID.customersiteid) as [Location],
       ID.mvengineeridname as [MV Engineer],
       ID.mvengineersecondaryidname as [MV Engineer Secondary],
       ID.ipmvpoptname as [IPMVP Option],
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + ECM.name FROM Filtered_ecm ECM JOIN Filtered_installation I on ECM.ecmid = I.ecmid WHERE I.initiativedetailid = ID.initiativedetailid for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as [ECM Description],
       (SELECT SUM(ESM.energysavings) FROM Filteredenergysavingsmeasurement ESM JOIN Filteredinstallation I on ESM.installationid = I.installationid WHERE ESM.energysavingstype=777790002 AND ESM.statecode=0 AND I.initiativedetailid=ID.initiativedetailid) as [Est. Annual Savings kWh], -- PSE Initial Review
       (SELECT SUM(ESM.energysavings) FROM Filteredenergysavingsmeasurement ESM JOIN Filteredinstallation I on ESM.installationid = I.installationid WHERE ESM.energysavingstype=100000003 AND ESM.statecode=0 AND I.initiativedetailid=ID.initiativedetailid) as [Site Inspection Savings kWh], -- PSE Site Inspection
       (SELECT TOP (1) ESM.MeasurementDate FROM Filteredenergysavingsmeasurement ESM JOIN Filteredinstallation I on ESM.installationid = I.installationid WHERE I.InitiativeDetailId = ID.InitiativeDetailId AND ESM.EnergySavingsType = 100000003 AND ESM.statecode=0 ORDER BY ESM.MeasurementDate Desc) as [Site Inspection Date],
       [Payment Date] =
       CASE
              WHEN NOT (SELECT TOP (1) C.datemet FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = I.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790000) IS NULL THEN (SELECT TOP (1) C.datemet FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = I.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790000)
              WHEN (SELECT SUM(C.partialpayment) FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = I.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790001) > 40 THEN (SELECT TOP(1) C.datemet FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = I.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790001 ORDER BY C.datemet Desc)
              ELSE Null
       END,
       ID.postretrofitpowermeteringinstallationdate as [Post-Retrofit Power Metering Installation Date],
       ID.postretrofitlightingloggerinstallationdat as [Post-Retrofit Lighting Loggers Installed Date],
       ID.mostrecentdatacollection as [Most Recent Data Collection Date],
       D.mvreportduedateextensiondays as [Final M&V Report Due Extention Days],
       [Trigger Based Final Report Due Date] =
       CASE
              -- Inspection Date is null
              WHEN (SELECT TOP (1) ESM.MeasurementDate FROM Filteredenergysavingsmeasurement ESM JOIN Filteredinstallation I on ESM.installationid = I.installationid WHERE I.InitiativeDetailId = ID.InitiativeDetailId AND ESM.EnergySavingsType = 100000003 AND ESM.statecode=0) IS NULL THEN NULL
              -- A, A&C, C, and B-Others without power metering
              WHEN (ID.ipmvpopt = 777790000 OR ID.ipmvpopt = 777790005 OR ID.ipmvpopt = 777790003
                     OR ((ID.ipmvpopt = 777790004 OR ID.ipmvpopt = 777790006) AND ID.postretrofitslamanalysisrequired <> 1 AND ID.postretrofitpowermeteringrequired <> 1)) THEN 
                     DATEADD(d, 
                           CASE
                                  WHEN (ID.ipmvpopt = 777790000 AND (SELECT TOP(1) D.datereceived FROM Filtereddeliverable D WHERE D.initiativedetailid=ID.InitiativeDetailId AND D.deliverabletype=777790008) IS NULL) THEN 1  --A without schedule C
                                  WHEN (ID.ipmvpopt = 777790000) THEN 196 --A with schedule C
                                  WHEN (ID.ipmvpopt = 777790004 OR ID.ipmvpopt = 777790006) THEN 412 -- B-Others
                                  ELSE 451 -- A&C or C
                           END,
                           (SELECT TOP (1) ESM.MeasurementDate FROM Filteredenergysavingsmeasurement ESM WHERE ESM.InitiativeDetailId = ID.InitiativeDetailId AND ESM.EnergySavingsType = 100000003 AND statecode=0 ORDER BY ESM.MeasurementDate Desc))
              -- B-others with power metering
              WHEN ((ID.ipmvpopt = 777790004 OR ID.ipmvpopt = 777790006) AND ID.postretrofitslamanalysisrequired <> 1 AND ID.postretrofitpowermeteringrequired = 1) THEN
                     CASE   
                           WHEN (ID.postretrofitpowermeteringinstallationdate IS NULL) THEN NULL--'Meters Required'
                           ELSE DATEADD(d, 421, ID.postretrofitpowermeteringinstallationdate)
                     END
              -- B-Ltg
              WHEN ((ID.ipmvpopt = 777790004 OR ID.ipmvpopt = 777790006) AND ID.postretrofitslamanalysisrequired = 1 AND ID.postretrofitpowermeteringrequired <> 1) THEN
                     CASE
                           WHEN (ID.postretrofitlightingloggerinstallationdat IS NULL) THEN NULL--'Loggers Required'
                           ELSE DATEADD(d, 414, ID.postretrofitlightingloggerinstallationdat)
                     END
              ELSE NULL--'UNKNOWN'
       END,
       [I&R Based Final Report Due Date] = 
       CASE
              WHEN NOT (SELECT TOP (1) C.datemet FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = I.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790000) IS NULL THEN DATEADD(d, 365, (SELECT TOP (1) C.datemet FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = I.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790000))
              WHEN (SELECT SUM(C.partialpayment) FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = I.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790001) > 75 THEN DATEADD(d, 365, (SELECT TOP(1) C.datemet FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = I.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790001 ORDER BY C.datemet Desc))
              ELSE NULL
       END,
       D.duedate as [Final M&V Report Due Date],
       D.loggersmetersrequired as [Loggers Or Meters Required],
       CASE
              WHEN (NOT D.mvreportauthor IS NULL) THEN 'Done'
              WHEN (D.duedate IS NULL) THEN 'N/A'
              WHEN (D.duedate > @Today) THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(16), DATEDIFF(d, @Today, D.duedate))
              ELSE 'Overdue'
       END as [Report Due In Days],
       @Organization
    FROM
       Filteredinitiative I
       JOIN Filteredinitiativedetail ID on I.initiativeid = ID.initiativeid
       join Filtereddeliverable d on i.initiativeid = d.initiativeid AND D.deliverabletype = 777790035 -- M&V Final Report
              and d.statecode = 0
       left join #DaysToAdd A On A.ipmvpopt = ID.ipmvpopt AND a.postretrofitpowermeteringrequired = ID.postretrofitpowermeteringrequired AND A.postretrofitslamanalysisrequired = ID.postretrofitslamanalysisrequired
     WHERE 
       -- Global Filters
       I.statecode = 0
       AND I.mvinvolvement = 1
       AND I.initiativetype = 777790003 --Incentive
       -- Query Logic
       -- Final MV Report Due Date is a date
       AND NOT D.duedate IS NULL
       -- Final MV report author is null     
       AND (D.mvreportcompletiondate is NULL OR D.mvanalysiscompletiondate is NULL )       
       -- Final MV Report Due Date - Final MV Report Preparation Time < Current Date
       AND (ID.ipmvpopt = 777790000 OR ID.ipmvpopt = 777790004 OR ID.ipmvpopt = 777790003 OR ID.ipmvpopt = 777790005 OR ID.ipmvpopt = 777790006)    
       AND DATEADD(d, A.daysAdded, D.duedate) < @Today

       DROP TABLE tempdb..#DaysToAdd
```

I Have tried to optimize it by removing :

Columns with the highest cost and then adding those columns back when I fetch rows from the temporary tables.

I reduced execution time  to 3:07 minutes. First Issue does not bring me back the expected dataset which should be 2346 rows (as the original query does) but bring back 2630 records instead.

The columns with inline example (SELECT TOP(1)......ORDER BY, and CASE etc seem to be costly. Can I optimize these and also mimick the original query above so that all data rows are fetched properly.)

**Question**:
Can you tell me a better way of optimizing this query?
FYI : We have added statistics on the required tables and have clustered and non-clustered indexes.
Is there a better way of optimizing this query correctly?
Is there a way of moving those SELECT TOP... ORDER BY into TEMP tables and reduce to optimizing it.?

**My optimized query is given below:**

```
DECLARE @Today as Smalldatetime = GetDate()
DECLARE @Organization as nvarchar(200) =  replace(db_name(), '_MSCRM', '')


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DaysToAdd', 'U') IS NULL   
BEGIN

       CREATE TABLE #DaysToAdd (
              ipmvpopt INT,
              postretrofitslamanalysisrequired BIT,
              postretrofitpowermeteringrequired BIT,
              daysAdded INT,       
              daysAddedFinal INT
       ) 

       INSERT INTO #DaysToAdd Values
              (777790000, 0, 0, -14, 196),
              (777790000, 0, 1, -14, 196),
              (777790000, 1, 0, -14, 196),
              (777790000, 1, 1, -14, 196),
              (777790004, 0, 0, -56, 412), 
              (777790004, 0, 1, -56, 412), 
              (777790004, 1, 0, -79, 412), 
              (777790004, 1, 1, -56, 412), 
              (777790006, 0, 0, -56, 412),
              (777790006, 0, 1, -56, 412),
              (777790006, 1, 0, -79, 412),
              (777790006, 1, 1, -56, 412),
              (777790005, 0, 0, -56, 451),
              (777790005, 0, 1, -56, 451),
              (777790005, 1, 0, -56, 451),
              (777790005, 1, 1, -56, 451),
              (777790003, 0, 0, -56, 451),
              (777790003, 0, 1, -56, 451),
              (777790003, 1, 0, -56, 451),
              (777790003, 1, 1, -56, 451)
END
SELECT
       distinct
       I.filenumber,
       I.initiativename,
       I.projectname,
       I.mvplancompletedon,
       I.owneridname,
       I.approveddatestep4,
       ID.initiativedetailid,
       ID.mvcomment,
           ID.mvengineeridname,
       ID.mvengineersecondaryidname,
       ID.ipmvpoptname,
                 ID.postretrofitpowermeteringinstallationdate,
       ID.postretrofitlightingloggerinstallationdat,
       ID.mostrecentdatacollection,
       D.mvreportduedateextensiondays,
          D.duedate as duedate,
       D.loggersmetersrequired,
           @Organization as Organization,
              D.mvreportcompletiondate,
              D.mvanalysiscompletiondate,
              ID.mvengineerid,
              ID.ipmvpopt,
              ID.requiredmeteringequipment,
              ID.preretrofitpowermeteringrequired,
              ID.postretrofitpowermeteringrequired,
              ID.preretrofitslamanalysisrequired,
              ID.postretrofitslamanalysisrequired,
              ID.customerbaselinedatarequired,
              ID.baselinecorrelationrequired,
              ID.casanalysisrequired,
              ID.customersiteid,
              ID.customerpostretrofitdatarequired,
              D.mvreportauthor, 
              I.initiativeId                       


INTO tempdb..#MainTable
FROM
       Filteredinitiative I
       JOIN Filteredinitiativedetail ID on I.initiativeid = ID.initiativeid       
       join Filtereddeliverable d on i.initiativeid = d.initiativeid AND D.deliverabletype = 777790035 -- M&V Final Report
              and d.statecode = 0
       left join #DaysToAdd A On A.ipmvpopt = ID.ipmvpopt AND a.postretrofitpowermeteringrequired = ID.postretrofitpowermeteringrequired AND A.postretrofitslamanalysisrequired = ID.postretrofitslamanalysisrequired
WHERE 
       -- Global Filters
       I.statecode = 0
       AND I.mvinvolvement = 1
       AND I.initiativetype = 777790003 --Incentive
       -- Query Logic
       -- Final MV Report Due Date is a date
       AND D.duedate IS NOT NULL
       -- Final MV report author is null 
       AND (D.mvreportcompletiondate is NULL OR D.mvanalysiscompletiondate is NULL )

       -- Final MV Report Due Date - Final MV Report Preparation Time < Current Date
       AND (ID.ipmvpopt = 777790000 OR ID.ipmvpopt = 777790004 OR ID.ipmvpopt = 777790003 OR ID.ipmvpopt = 777790005 OR ID.ipmvpopt = 777790006)

       AND DATEADD(d, A.daysAdded, D.duedate) < @Today 


Select  main.filenumber as [File #],
       main.initiativename as [Initiative Name],
       main.projectname as [Project Name],
       main.mvplancompletedon as [M&V Plan Completion Date],
       main.owneridname  as [Key Account Manager],
       main.approveddatestep4  as [Signed Agreement Recieved Date],
       main.initiativedetailid,
       main.mvcomment as [Comments],
          [Data Incomplete] =
       CASE
              WHEN (main.mvengineerid IS NULL OR main.ipmvpopt IS NULL OR main.requiredmeteringequipment IS NULL OR
              main.preretrofitpowermeteringrequired IS NULL OR main.postretrofitpowermeteringrequired IS NULL OR
              main.customerpostretrofitdatarequired IS NULL OR main.preretrofitslamanalysisrequired IS NULL OR
              main.postretrofitslamanalysisrequired IS NULL OR main.customerbaselinedatarequired IS NULL OR
              main.baselinecorrelationrequired IS NULL OR main.casanalysisrequired IS NULL) THEN 'Yes'
              ELSE 'No'
       END,
       (SELECT TOP (1) [Location] = CASE WHEN (NOT s.serviceaddress_city IS NULL) THEN s.serviceaddress_city + ' / ' + S.name ELSE S.name END FROM Filteredsite S WHERE S.siteid = main.customersiteid) as [Location],

          main.mvengineeridname  as [MV Engineer],
       main.mvengineersecondaryidname  as [MV Engineer Secondary],
       main.ipmvpoptname  as [IPMVP Option],
          STUFF((SELECT ',' + ECM.name FROM Filteredecm ECM JOIN Filteredinstallation I on ECM.ecmid = I.ecmid WHERE I.initiativedetailid = main.initiativedetailid for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as [ECM Description],
       (SELECT SUM(ESM.energysavings) FROM Filteredenergysavingsmeasurement ESM JOIN Filteredinstallation I on ESM.installationid = I.installationid WHERE ESM.energysavingstype=777790002 AND ESM.statecode=0 AND I.initiativedetailid=main.initiativedetailid) as [Est. Annual Savings kWh], -- PSE Initial Review
       (SELECT SUM(ESM.energysavings) FROM Filteredenergysavingsmeasurement ESM JOIN Filteredinstallation I on ESM.installationid = I.installationid WHERE ESM.energysavingstype=100000003 AND ESM.statecode=0 AND I.initiativedetailid=main.initiativedetailid) as [Site Inspection Savings kWh], -- PSE Site Inspection
       (SELECT TOP (1) ESM.MeasurementDate FROM Filteredenergysavingsmeasurement ESM JOIN Filteredinstallation I on ESM.installationid = I.installationid WHERE I.InitiativeDetailId = main.InitiativeDetailId AND ESM.EnergySavingsType = 100000003 AND ESM.statecode=0 ORDER BY ESM.MeasurementDate Desc) as [Site Inspection Date],
       [Payment Date] =
       CASE
              WHEN NOT (SELECT TOP (1) C.datemet FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = main.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790000) IS NULL THEN (SELECT TOP (1) C.datemet FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = main.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790000)
              WHEN (SELECT SUM(C.partialpayment) FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = main.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790001) > 40 THEN (SELECT TOP(1) C.datemet FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = main.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790001 ORDER BY C.datemet Desc)
              ELSE Null
       END,
           main.postretrofitpowermeteringinstallationdate  as [Post-Retrofit Power Metering Installation Date],
       main.postretrofitlightingloggerinstallationdat  as [Post-Retrofit Lighting Loggers Installed Date],
       main.mostrecentdatacollection  as [Most Recent Data Collection Date],
       main.mvreportduedateextensiondays as [Final M&V Report Due Extention Days],
          [Trigger Based Final Report Due Date] =
       CASE
              -- Inspection Date is null
              WHEN (SELECT TOP (1) ESM.MeasurementDate FROM Filteredenergysavingsmeasurement ESM JOIN Filteredinstallation I on ESM.installationid = I.installationid WHERE I.InitiativeDetailId = main.InitiativeDetailId AND ESM.EnergySavingsType = 100000003 AND ESM.statecode=0) IS NULL THEN NULL
              -- A, A&C, C, and B-Others without power metering
              WHEN (main.ipmvpopt = 777790000 OR main.ipmvpopt = 777790005 OR main.ipmvpopt = 777790003
                     OR ((main.ipmvpopt = 777790004 OR main.ipmvpopt = 777790006) AND main.postretrofitslamanalysisrequired <> 1 AND main.postretrofitpowermeteringrequired <> 1)) THEN 
                     DATEADD(d, 
                           CASE
                                  WHEN (main.ipmvpopt = 777790000 AND (SELECT TOP(1) D.datereceived FROM Filtereddeliverable D WHERE D.initiativedetailid=main.InitiativeDetailId AND D.deliverabletype=777790008) IS NULL) THEN 1  --A without schedule C
                                  WHEN (main.ipmvpopt = 777790000) THEN 196 --A with schedule C
                                  WHEN (main.ipmvpopt = 777790004 OR main.ipmvpopt = 777790006) THEN 412 -- B-Others
                                  ELSE 451 -- A&C or C
                           END,
                           (SELECT TOP (1) ESM.MeasurementDate FROM Filteredenergysavingsmeasurement ESM WHERE ESM.InitiativeDetailId = main.InitiativeDetailId AND ESM.EnergySavingsType = 100000003 AND statecode=0 ORDER BY ESM.MeasurementDate Desc))
              -- B-others with power metering
              WHEN ((main.ipmvpopt = 777790004 OR main.ipmvpopt = 777790006) AND main.postretrofitslamanalysisrequired <> 1 AND main.postretrofitpowermeteringrequired = 1) THEN
                     CASE   
                           WHEN (main.postretrofitpowermeteringinstallationdate IS NULL) THEN NULL--'Meters Required'
                           ELSE DATEADD(d, 421, main.postretrofitpowermeteringinstallationdate)
                     END
              -- B-Ltg
              WHEN ((main.ipmvpopt = 777790004 OR main.ipmvpopt = 777790006) AND main.postretrofitslamanalysisrequired = 1 AND main.postretrofitpowermeteringrequired <> 1) THEN
                     CASE
                           WHEN (main.postretrofitlightingloggerinstallationdat IS NULL) THEN NULL--'Loggers Required'
                           ELSE DATEADD(d, 414, main.postretrofitlightingloggerinstallationdat)
                     END
              ELSE NULL--'UNKNOWN'
       END,
       [I&R Based Final Report Due Date] = 
       CASE
              WHEN NOT (SELECT TOP (1) C.datemet FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = main.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790000) IS NULL THEN DATEADD(d, 365, (SELECT TOP (1) C.datemet FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = main.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790000))
              WHEN (SELECT SUM(C.partialpayment) FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = main.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790001) > 75 THEN DATEADD(d, 365, (SELECT TOP(1) C.datemet FROM Filteredcommitment C WHERE C.initiativeid = main.initiativeId AND C.commitmenttype = 777790001 ORDER BY C.datemet Desc))
              ELSE NULL
       END,
          main.duedate as [Final M&V Report Due Date],
       main.loggersmetersrequired as [Loggers Or Meters Required],
          CASE
              WHEN (main.mvreportauthor IS NOT NULL) THEN 'Done'
              WHEN (main.duedate IS NULL) THEN 'N/A'
              WHEN (main.duedate > @Today) THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(16), DATEDIFF(d, @Today, main.duedate))
              ELSE 'Overdue'
       END as [Report Due In Days],
           @Organization as Organization
FROM tempdb..#MainTable main


DROP TABLE tempdb..#MainTable
```

Comment: Your subqueries in the select clause are causing your problems, I think.

Comment: Could you provide the statistics that are output when you execute your optimized query with SET STATISTICS TIME,IO ON

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at the execution plan? That will tell you were you bottlenecks are and help you know where to focus your optimization efforts.

Here is a good intro: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

Once you know what parts of the query are slow, you can ask about specific problem areas.